# What would happen if I submit a non-spark jar to cluster via spark-submit?

Tags: java, apache-spark

Not very clear about the whole picture of spark. Let's say I create a regular java jar, without involving any spark relevant things, no sparksession, no sparkcontext, no rdd, no dataset, then what would happen if I submit it to spark cluster via spark-submit with deply-mode=cluster?

I wrote a simple jar which only prints some lines, and seems it works fine on my toy spark, I once thought that would result in some error since it's not a spark application...

I wonder to know if I can expect same result when submitting to a real-world spark cluster which has many nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can depend on a cluster manager and mode but in general nothing strange. Spark application is a plain JVM application with normal `main` function, it doesn't implement particular interface and lack of active session is not an issue.

Comment: So when lack of active session, will there still be one driver and multiple executors, or only the driver?

Comment: Spark will spin up a cluster that you request via spark submit and run the code only on the driver.